# Understanding this part of an automotive wiring schematic

Tags: operational-amplifier, motor, schematics, automotive

I'm trying to figure out this part of a wiring schematic for a car's rear wiper assembly, but I am confused by the circled part that shows two prongs sticking out and a dash line going to their top. What is this and how does this work?

Voltage at terminal C is always 12V, voltage at B is always 0V. While the wiper relay is open and the motor is not working, the voltage at A is 0V. It goes to 12V when the motor is spinning.

[image: What's going on here?]

Comment: Embed the schematic dude.

Comment: It's a reversing switch linked to the motor and likely ultimately linked to the wiper blade position.

Comment: Embed? Embed into what? It's a service manual scan.

Comment: A switch makes sense, I kind of expected a switch to look a bit different, with a prong on one side only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mechanically operated switch**

So that the wiper can always go back to the starting point, even if the relay turns off when it's half way up the screen.  It's drawn a bit funny - normally you'd only draw one of the branches. The wiper can run from the always-on input at any point in it's travel except the home position.  There, it needs power from the other input, the relay-controlled one, to start it off.

One of the comments suggests this is a reversing switch, but I don't think that's right.  Reversing switches would need to be wired more like a H-bridge, and would be in series with this switch.  Most cars do not use a reversing switch, instead they use a mechanical mechanism to turn a continuous rotation of the motor into reciprocating motion of the wiper.
[image]
<sup>[Image from http://ch00ftech.com, where someone is trying to make their wipers move in time with the beats from the stereo]</sup>

The green pin (P1) goes to the motor, and is always connected to the metal track on the green disk.  P2 is connected to the always-on power, so most of the time the metal track connects the motor to the power.  When the wiper is in or near the home position, the P2 pin is not touching the metal track, so the motor is not powered.  The switched live (A in your schematic) is separately & permanently connected to the motor.  Most cars use something similar.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Is there enough information in the schematic to figure out how exactly it works?

Comment: In the schematic no, but I have taken one apart before so I know how it might work.  I'll see if I can find a picture online.

Comment: Read the new information you added, quite a clever system. A strange way to draw it this way, but I guess drawing automotive electrical schematics is not an easy job when there are these sort of things going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As @JackB said, it's a mechanically operated switch.

From the schematic we can read that:

In the resting position of the wiper the switch is in the upper position. This way, the motor is connected to +12V via the relay K56. Hence, it starts moving when that relay closes.

Now, while the wiper is moving, i.e. not in its resting position, the motor's switch is in the lower position, connecting the motor directly to +12V, bypassing K56. This way the motor stays powered even if the K56 turns it off. And it keeps moving until it is back in the resting position, which is when the motor's switch moves to the upper position again, disconnecting the direct +12V and connecting the switched +12V from the relay again.
If the relay is still closed the circle starts over again, else the motor turns itself off because it doesn't get +12V anymore.